# Doubt in step in the proof of theorem 6.11 in Rudin's book

Tags: calculus

I want to understand a step in baby Rudin's theorem 6.11. The theorem says the follwing: Let $f$ be Rieman-Stieljes integrable in $[a,b]$. Let $m\leq f\leq M$. Let $\phi:[m,M]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Then $h(x)=\phi(f(x))$ is Rieman-Stieljes integrable in $[a,b]$.

The proof goes like this. Since $\phi$ is continuous in a compact set it is uniformly continuous in $[m,M]$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then we can pick $\delta<\epsilon$ such that $|s,t|\leq\delta$ imply that $|\phi(s)-\phi(t)|<\epsilon$, where $s,t\in[m,M]$.

Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$.
$$
a=x_0\leq x_2\leq\ldots\leq x_n=b
$$
let $\Delta x_i=x_i-x_{i-1}$. Let $M_i=sup\{f(\Delta x_i)\}$ and $m_i=inf\{f(\Delta x_i)\}$. Let $M_i^*=sup\{h(\Delta x_i)\}$ and $m_i^*=inf\{h(\Delta x_i)\}$.

Let's divide the intervals in $P$ in two categories. if $M_i-m_i<\delta$ then $i\in A$. If not $i\in B$.

Ok, so far so good, no problems. The hext thing he says is, for $i\in A$ our choice of $\delta$ shows that $M_i^*-m_i^*\leq\epsilon$. Can you prove this?

Comment: I think it should say $M_i=\sup \{f(x):x\in [x_{i-1},x_i]\}$, with similar changes in the def'ns of $m_i, M^*_i,$  and $m^*_i.$. As written, we have $M_i=f(x_i-x_{i-1}).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $i \in A$, i.e. $M_i - m_i < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M_i - m_i < \delta$ for all $x,y$ from the $i$-th interval.

Then $|h(x) - h(y)| = |\phi(f(x)) - \phi(f(y))| < \epsilon$ for any $x,y$ from the $i$-th interval -- by the choice of $\epsilon/\delta$.

$M_i^* - m_i^* \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \sup_{\text{such } x} h(x) - \inf_{\text{such } y} h(y) \leq \sup_{\text{such x,y}}|h(x) - h(y)| \leq \epsilon$, where "such" means "from the interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$".

Comment: How do you know $M_i^*-m_i^*\leq sup|h(x)-h(y)|\leq\epsilon$?

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus: cf. edit; I would help if you could be more explicit where your problem is

Comment: I have a problem with $\sup_{\text{such } x} h(x) - \inf_{\text{such } y} h(y)\leq \sup_{\text{such x,y}}|h(x) - h(y)|$. How do you justify that?

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus: $\sup_x h(x) - \inf_y h(y) = \sup_{x,y} (h(x) - h(y))$. There just isn't much to justify